# Inserting an array to a 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to insert some result arrays to a 2d array. but at the end i only get all the 2d arrays with the set of last array i inserted in to the 2d array. when i debug and check the code i found that every time i do this action `bmma[il]=number;` the bmma array's all arrays changes with the newly assigning values.

here is the full code i implemented.

```
double[][] newDATA ;
double [][] bmma = new double[100][];

double [] number = new double[12];
int il=0;
  String fname = "newAudio.wav";

  RawAudioFileStream rawAudio = new RawAudioFileStream(fname);
  StreamHeader mh = mfccm.init(rawAudio.getHeader());
  MatrixFileStream out = new MatrixFileStream(fname + ".txt", true);
  out.setMultiLine(true);
  out.setHeader(mh);


  while (true) {
    StreamFrame f = mfccm.process(rawAudio.recvFrame());

    if (f == null) {
      break;
    }

    if(((MatrixHeader.MatrixFrame)f).data != null){

      for (int i=0;i<12;i++){

        newDATA=((MatrixHeader.MatrixFrame)f).data;
        number[i]=newDATA[i][0];

      }

      bmma[il]=number;
      il++;
    }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one array assigned to `number` (the one you instantiate here - `double [] number = new double[12];`), and you assign this array multiple times to the `bmma` 2D array, so all rows of the 2D arrays will be identical.

You should create a new array for each row of the 2D array :

```
  number = new double[12];
  for (int i=0;i<12;i++){

    newDATA=((MatrixHeader.MatrixFrame)f).data;
    number[i]=newDATA[i][0];

  }

  bmma[il]=number;
```

Comment: I cant even realise i did this simple mistake :(. thanks alot for the help. working on a heavy deadline no words to say.